# A heavy burden to bear. Should 'to bear' closely follow 'burden'?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> Psychotic disorders are a heavy burden for the affected patients and
>   their environment to bear

Is it erroneous to split 'a heavy burden to bear'?  I feel as if 'burden' and 'to bear' should be closer together in that sentence. It reminds me somewhat of a split infinitive.

Comment: Ask yourself what is the subject of the infinitival clause "to bear"?

Comment: There's no real need for them to be adjacent, but you could if you wish  re-word it "Psychotic disorders are a heavy burden to bear for the affected patients and their environment. Either way, you have what's sometimes called a "hollow infinitival clause" since the object of the verb "bear" is missing.

Comment: Only people can bear a burden; not an environment. Don't much care for calling people around other people, their environment.  for the affected patients and those around them.

Comment: No, "environments" can bear burdens, e.g. "The local environment had to bear the burden of the intensive use of pesticides by local farmers".